# Copy Dynamic range text into another range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a bit of code that will copy the value of one specific Named Range cell into another Named Range.

The code is as follows:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("RaceDrop")) Is Nothing Then
    If Range("RaceDrop") = Range("Races").Cells(1, 1) And Range("ClassDrop") = Range("Classes").Cells(1, 1) Or Range("Races").Cells(1, 1) And Range("ClassDrop") = Range("Classes").Cells(1, 2) Then
         Range("OriginDrop") = Range("Origins").Cells(1, 1)
```

Every statement like "Range("X") = Range("Y").Cells(x, x)" gives an error, in the If Statement and in the result.  But if I make it a static statement, such as "Human" for Range("Races").Cells(1, 1).  While this workaround works, I would like to make all references dynamic so it takes much less time to change or move data values.

I've tried Range("Origins").Cells(1, 1).Text for example, but it still doesn't work.  Is there another way to go about this?

Edit: I should also add that the error I get is "Method 'Range' of Object '_Worksheet' failed"

Added:

The references with Cells() are because they refer to actual ranges, not just one cell.  Some refer to large tables, so sometimes it will be Range("Table").Cells(5, 3), it doesn't always refer to 1, 1.  I'm not sure of another way to refer to a specific cell in a table than that.

For example, one bit i would like to do is:
Range("OriginDrop") = Range("Origins").Cells(4, 1)

Comment: This part of your `If` statement  doesn't make any sense: `... Or Range("Races").Cells(1, 1) And ...` Just testing that one cell on its own without comparing it to anything else would only work if that cell was expected to hold a Boolean value - i.e. True or False

Comment: It does make sense.  IF X and A Or X and B.  The code continues to test IF Y and A or Y and B, there is also an X and C and so on.  So if it doesn't test both values, then it would end at the wrong part.  If I only tested X, it would result in C being skipped, as it's checked later and has a different result.  For example, when I first made it, I just did IF X and A or B, IF Y and A or B, it would always result in the first line because it wast just "or B", so Y and B would never be used.  The entire check has to be in there.  Believe me, it makes sense.

Comment: The updated code in your answer below changes that part to `... or Range("Races") = Sheets("Data").Range("Races").Cells(1, 1) and ...` Not sure if your question had a typo but you weren't comparing `Range("Races").Cells(1, 1)` to anything at that point in the code presented in your question

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- Use `Range("RaceDrop").Value` to indicate the actual value of the cell. Most of the time `Range("RaceDrop") =` will work but it is best to always explicitly say `.Value`
- I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do with the `Cells(1,1)` part of your code, but if you are looking to find the top left value in the range, try something like the below code

replace

```
Range("Races").Cells(1, 1)
```

with

```
Cells(Range("Races").row, Range("Races").column).Value
```

If the cells you are referring to are named `Ranges` of only a single `Cell` you should be able to use just

```
Range("Races").Value
```

instead of the above.

Comment: The references with Cells() are because they refer to actual ranges, not just one cell.  Some refer to large tables, so sometimes it will be Range("Table").Cells(5, 3), it doesn't always refer to 1, 1.  I'm not sure of another way to refer to a specific cell in a table than that.

For example, one bit i would like to do is:
Range("OriginDrop") = Range("Origins").Cells(4, 1)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  Normally, I don't have to specifically type the sheet that the data is on, because the tables work globally (usually I just have Range("Table") and it works regardless of where the code is at because it always knows where to refer to) however.. it seems that since I'm trying to copy data from a table into a table on another sheet, it doesn't work that way, and needs the Sheets("") to be defined.

Kind of odd how it always seems to work globally except in this instance.  Oh well.  Thanks for trying.

Example of new code:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("RaceDrop")) Is Nothing Then
If Range("RaceDrop") = Sheets("Data").Range("Races").Cells(1, 1) and Range("ClassDrop") = Sheets("Data").Range("Classes").Cells(1, 1) or Range("Races") = Sheets("Data").Range("Races").Cells(1, 1) and Ranges("ClassDrop") = Sheets("Data").Range("Classes").Cells(2, 1)
     Range("OriginDrop") = Sheets("Data").Range("Origins").Cells(1, 1)
```